# Does the C++ Spec treat the std library special?

Tags: c++

It was my impression that std library was not special to a C++ compiler, just special because every vendor ships an implementation of it, and otherwise it's just code written in C++ usable in C++ just like any other code written in C++.

I have seen a few places that seem to disagree with this, such as how user-defined literal suffixes must begin with an underscore because "the suffixes that do not begin with the underscore are reserved for the literal operators provided by the standard library". https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal

Does the spec really have different rules for the std library than for other C++ code to be compiled? Are C++ compilers hard-coded to recognize code in std library and "do something different"?

This is really upsetting my internal image of how this whole system works together...

Comment: I've yet to see a C++ library that was not specific to a C++ compiler.  The C++ standard as the specification does not mandate that there are special rules for the C++ library, other than what the C++ library is supposed to provide at a minimum.

Comment: One interesting deviation is the Library implementors almost always are writing the library to package with a particular compiler and know how that compiler will interpret certain undefined behaviours. You can expect the library to do things that you should not do because they know they can get away with it (and probably have a good reason for doing it).

Answer (score 2):

The library is mostly as you describe, though there are exceptions.

The problem with literals that you mention [*may* be a defect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59180565/4386278). Even if this is so, however, a name clash within the implementation is completely avoidable in practice, since it's a single group of people writing it.

Furthermore, [some standard library features actually cannot be implemented without compiler support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45194749/4386278).

So it's a bit of a mixed bag.