# Process of how libraries are added to C++'s STL?

Tags: c++, std, ieee

What kind of process or vetting do libraries go through in order to be added to the STL? Do they have to meet some sort of standard imposed by the IEEE?

Comment: all you need to get you started is here: https://isocpp.org/std

Comment: There's a committee that decides that: https://isocpp.org/std/the-committee

Comment: The IEEE is not involved. Perhaps you're confusing them with ISO?

Comment: You should read [What's the difference between "STL" and "C++ Standard Library"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-the-difference-between-stl-and-c-standard-library/5205571#5205571).

Comment: Not quite a dupe, but definitely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45194205/how-to-and-who-can-implement-the-standard-library-features-defined-by-the-c

Comment: @molbdnilo: Or IEC. ISO and IEC have a Joint Technical Committee, whose Subcommittee 22 works on Programming Languages. That's why the C++ committee ends up as JTC1/SC22/WG21. JTC1 has a cooperation agreement with IEEE, which includes e.g. IEEE754 floating point

Comment: Quite some libraries go through Boost (www.boost.org).